# Can a Force Close error on Android be perceived?

Tags: android, forceclose

Is it possible for an application or rather a service to perceive if any application on the phone has force closed? If so, how would this be implemented? If not, why? Is there a possible work around?

Comment: Is it your own application? You can install an Error Handler for you own application. I doubt there is a possiblity to install a system wide error handler without having root access.

Comment: No, not my own application. Every possible application.

Root access is required? That's fine, how would I go about implementing this?